# What are the “costs” to find a pre-image, weak collision, or strong collision?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, security-definition, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

For a secure, n-bit hash function, what are the “costs” to find a pre-image, weak collision, or strong collision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2004 paper, [Rogaway and Shrimpton gave reference](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/relates.pdf) to Merkle's paper

- 1998 : [One Way Hash Functions and DES](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_40)

and they Merkle's definitions simply as

> Contemporaneously, Merkle [10] describes notions of hash-function security: **weak collision resistance** and **strong collision resistance**, which refer to **second-preimage** and **collision resistance**, respectively.

Since we are talking about attacks, let's convert the definitions into;

**Attack Definitions:**

- In the **pre-image attack**, given a hash function $H$ and a hash value $h$, we try to find $x$ such that $h = H(x)$. The $x$ need not be the original input value used to calculate the hash $h$.
- In the **second preimage attack ( breaking weak collision resistance)**; we are given $H,x,h$ with $h = H(x)$ and we need to find another $x'$ such that $h = H(x')$.
- **Collision attack (breaking strong collision resistance)**; we are looking for two different inputs $a$ and $b$ such that  such that $H(a)=H(b)$.

**Costs:**

- The cost of pre-image and secondary pre-image is $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$

  The usual search for preimage and secondary pre-image is either iterating from 0 to $c\cdot2^n$ or randomly testing $c\cdot2^n$ values from a larger space then $2^n$.
- The cost of the collision is $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$ with 50% probability and this is due to the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

  The naive way is generating $2^{n/2}$ input hash pairs and sort them according to hash values. This costs around $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$ space.

  A better way is using [Pollard's Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) <sup>*</sup>;

  1. Pick a random hash value $h_1$ and set $h_1' = h_1$
  2. Compute $h_2 = H(h_1)$ and $h_2' = H(H(h_1'))$. That is one is slow one is fast.
  3. continue the process $h_{i+1} = H(h_i)$ and $h_{i+1}' = H(H(h_i'))$ until we reach an index $j$ such that $h_{j+1} = h_{j+1}'$

  We can visualize this algorithm as below; The algorithm eventually enter a cycle (the Rho-Shape)

  [image]

  The path to $h_5$ is a collision. The cycle length and the collision points can be found by [Floyds algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_Tortoise_and_Hare).

  This requires $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$ operations to find the collision.

  If we ask, what is the average cycle length is? If we model the hash function as uniform random then this is shown by [Harris in 1960](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237803). For a hash function with $\ell$ bit output, the average cycle length is $\frac{1}{ 2} \sqrt{2 \pi \ell}$ for SHA256 that makes $2^{127} \sqrt{\pi}$. That makes it quite unreachable for a hash function with 256-bit output to run the cycle to find a collision

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>In other context this is also known as [Floyd Cycle detection algorith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_Tortoise_and_Hare) (Floyd's Tortoise and Hare).  Knuth attributing it to Floyd, without a citation. The origin is not known.</sub>

---

Pollard Rho's with python

```
import hashlib
import secrets

def blake2b32(data):
    hasher = hashlib.blake2b(digest_size=6)
    hasher.update(data)
    return hasher.digest()

def pollard_rho(h):
    # Initialize both x and y with the same value
    x = y = h
    d = 1
    previous_x = x
    previous_y = y

    count = 0

    while d != 0:

        x = blake2b32(x)
        y = blake2b32(blake2b32(y))

        # Convert bytes to integers for bitwise XOR
        x_int = int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big')
        y_int = int.from_bytes(y, byteorder='big')

        # Perform bitwise XOR
        d_int = x_int ^ y_int

        # Convert the result back to a bytes object
        d = d_int.to_bytes(6, byteorder='big')

        previous_x = x
        previous_y = blake2b32(y)

        if d == b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00':
            print("Found collision!")
            print("x:", previous_x.hex())
            print("y:", previous_y.hex())

            print("count", count)

            return previous_x, previous_y

        count = count + 1

    print("count", count)

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Generate a random hash value
    h = secrets.randbelow(2**32).to_bytes(6, byteorder='big')

    # Find a collision for the hash value
    result = pollard_rho(h)

    if result:
        x, y = result
        print("Input values that have the collision:")
        print("x:", x.hex())
        print("y:", y.hex())
    else:
        print("No collision found")
```

with an output

```
Found collision!
x: 63ebb4a1a3cb
y: 6858c12e10e5
count 11526583
Input values that have the collision:
x: 63ebb4a1a3cb
y: 6858c12e10e5

real    0m24,966s
user    0m24,931s
sys     0m0,012s
```

1. Note that for 4 bytes it was less than 1 second.
2. I've used Bard and corrected it many times, and finally I've changed the random with secrets that it again failed to replace...

Comment: I've looked for dupe but couldn't. If you see let close this question.

Comment: @fgrieu `Contemporaneously, Merkle [10] describes notions of hash-function security: weak collision resistance and strong collision resistance, which refer to second-preimage and collision resistance, respectively.` from [Cryptographic Hash-Function Basics: Definitions, Implications, and Separations for Preimage Resistance, Second-Preimage Resistance, and Collision Resistance](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/relates.pdf) To be honest, in my ears, too.

Comment: interesting that there is no duplicate. nice historical context as well